# Подключение апи Яндекс Карт в реакт приложение, не используя react-yandex-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать в проекте Яндекс Карты, не прибегая к использованию сторонних библиотек. Документация, к сожалению не предоставляет конкретной информации по подключению. Я пробовал использовать react-yandex-maps, но этот вариант мне не подходит.

Comment: Подобные библиотеки создаются для простоты использования, чем именно не подходит?

Comment: Я понимаю для чего нужны библиотеки, и конкретно react-yandex-maps. Такой вариант мне не подходит, потому как я делаю учебный проект, одним из условий которого является реализация карт без внедрения в проект  подобных сторонних библиотек

Comment: Посмотрите их исходники на гитхабе и сделайте что-то похожее свое, тут Вам вряд ли кто будет это писать тем более по правилам ресурса учебные задания без попытки решить самостоятельно не подлежат ответам. Главное понимать разницу между реактом и обычным ванильным приложением(приложением без фреймворка)